# A problem with adding objects to a list in a loop

Tags: r, list, raster

Sorry if it is inappropriate. I checked all other posts but couldn't solve it.

I am trying to split a stacked raster object to each band and add them to a list as below:

```
library(rgdal)
satImage <- "pla18_rgbn_ndvi_7stack_16bit.img"


x <- vector("list", 35)

for (i in 1:35) {

  psi <- raster(satImage, band = i)
  x[[i]] <- psi

}
```

However it produces a list as below:

```
> View(x)
> x
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

...

[[34]]
NULL

[[35]]
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 35  (of  35  bands)
dimensions  : 13084, 18025, 235839100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 3, 3  (x, y)
extent      : 581337, 635412, 4425114, 4464366  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : E:/betul/35bantli/pla18_rgbn_ndvi_7stack_16bit.img 
names       : pla18_rgbn_ndvi_7stack_16bit 
values      : 55, 65535  (min, max)
```

I want all other 34 bands in the list. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It was really dumb to forget that one :( I changed but the problem is not solved

Comment: Please make your example reproducible! ... and from which package is `raster()`?

Comment: @jogo Yes I know but how can I create a reproducible image, I really don't know!

It is rgdal package.

Comment: At lease give a link to an example image (using a server to upload the image).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this

```
library(raster)
satImage <- "pla18_rgbn_ndvi_7stack_16bit.img"
s <- stack(satImage)
x <- as.list(s)
```

Now with example data:

```
f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster") 
s <- stack(f)
x <- as.list(s)
```

Checking the "band" number

```
sapply(x, bandnr)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

If you know the number of bands (3 in this case), what you were doing should work (but the above is more elegant):

```
f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")
n <- 3    
x <- vector("list", n)
for (i in 1:n) {
    x[[i]] <- raster(f, band = i)
}
```

Finally: you do not provide context, but you are probably better off by creating a `RasterStack` (as I show above) or, better still, a `RasterBrick`, instead of a list of `RasterLayer` objects